# i have some problems making a tcp server form a book in python , it shows OS error

Tags: python

```
import socket
import threading

bind_ip = '192.168.43.233'
print(f"[*] connecting to " + bind_ip)
bind_port = 443

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.listen(5)

print(f"[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip,bind_port))
def handle_client(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(f"[*] Recieved: %s" % request)
    client_socket.send("ACK!")

    client_socket.close()

while True:
    client,addr = server.accept()
    print(f"[*] Accepted connection from: %s:%d" % (addr[0],addr[1]))

    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(client,))
    client_handler.start()
```

says this when running

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Red/PycharmProjects/untitled4/TCP SERVEr.py", line 9, in <module>
    server.listen(5)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

any help with this so much appreciated ive been dealing with this for days now and looked everywhere but found nothing

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `server.listen()` until you bind the socket to a port.

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the socket before `server.listen(5)`.

```
connection.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
```

Comment: thank you, it's working now, ive struggled on this for while, your comment helped my day